# selenium throws an error on js although everything works fine in a normal browser

Tags: python, selenium

selenium throws an error on js although everything works fine in a normal browser

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('sc-1ebmiy2-0 dCqZTO iazzsz-1 jCFojM  landed')[2].click()")

time.sleep(60)
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("menu-_8r4li9v button-reABrhVR apply-common-tooltip")[0].click()')
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('item-RhC5uhZw')[9].click()")
```

console

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'click')
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` is not returning an element, which means, either the element doesn't exist in the browser session or perhaps, the class name is different. It looks like the class names are dynamically generated. Passing a static value would not work since they are newly generated every request.